# A way to list all user or app-created broadcasters?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way to list all broadcasts that were created by non-system applications?

I want to obtain a list of every app, service or broadcastReceiver that listens to system (or whatever) intents. Is is possible?

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to list all broadcasts that were created by non-system applications?

No.

> I want to obtain a list of every app, service or broadcastReceiver that listens to system (or whatever) intents. Is is possible?

You are welcome to build yourself a list of all "system (or whatever) intents", whatever that means. You are then welcome to use `PackageManager` and methods like `queryIntentActivities()` to determine what components will respond to them. This will not cover any `BroadcastReceivers` registered dynamically via `registerReceiver()`.